# iText7 PdfDocument save to two locations on disk

Tags: c#, itext7

In the code below I want to be able to read in a PDF file and add some encryption and then resave the file. what is the best way to do that? I dont see a `Save` method in pdfDocument is there another object I should use?

```
PdfReader pdfReader = null;
byte[] bytesPassword = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("PassWord");
WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
PdfDocument pdfDocument = null;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
       pdfReader = new PdfReader(destFile);
       writerProperties.SetStandardEncryption(null, bytesPassword, EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING, EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_256);
       pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, new PdfWriter(ms, writerProperties));
       pdfDocument.Close();
    }
   //pdfDocument.Save(FilePath1)
   //pdfDocument.Save(FilePath2)
```

Comment: Guess what the stream `ms` is for...

Comment: Do I need to use a `byte[]` and something like `WriteAllBytes`

Comment: You can also use `ms.Position = 0` and then `ms.CopyTo`.